# AnkhSVN Cannot Connect Due to Proxy

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2005, proxy, ankhsvn

Alright, this might be a bit of a long shot, but I have having problems getting AnkhSVN to connect from Visual Studio 2005 to an external SVN server. There is a network proxy in the way, but I can't seem to find a way in AnkhSVN to configure the proxy and doesn't seem to be detecting the Internet Explorer proxy configuration. Is there any way to resolve this issue, or will it likely just not work?

Comment: This feature has been implemented in the daily builds (http://ankhsvn.net/daily). It will be available in the next release.

Comment: @Bert - Glad hear it. Keep up the good work on AnkhSVN!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use TortoiseSVN for editting the proxy settings.

TortoiseSVN saves the settings in the registry in the common location that all Subversion  clients (by default) use.

*UPDATE*: A proxy settings dialog is now implemented in the AnkhSVN daily builds.
It will be available in the next release.

Answer (score 5):

Current version of AnkhSVN does not provide a GUI for proxy settings, but you can hand-edit the **servers** file (which is a simple .ini) and it should work.

Servers file resides in: **C:\Documents and Settings\YOU\Application Data\Subversion** (or wherever your APP_DATA is)